# Running database query in FragmentStatePagerAdapter NPE

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am trying to run a query against my database to get some data (which changes page to page) from my database.  I am getting a NullPointerException at `Double balance = db.getSum();`  Below is the full code of my fragmentstatepageradapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int listSize;
    String[] tabNames;
    String tabName;
    protected Context mContext;

    /** Constructor of the class */
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        final DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        Double balance = db.getSum(); //NPE here*******************
        tabName = "[" + getPageTitle(arg0) + "]";
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt("current_page", arg0 + 1);
        data.putString("tabName", tabName);
        mainFragment.setArguments(data);
        return mainFragment;
    }

    /** Returns the number of pages */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listSize;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabNames[position];
    }

    public void setCount(int count){
        listSize = count;
    }

    public void setNames(String[] names) {
        tabNames = names;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Here is my database getSum()

```
// GET SUM
    public Double getSum(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(credit), SUM(debit) FROM " + TABLE_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            sum = (c.getDouble(0) - c.getDouble(1));
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

And here is the error I am getting

```
07-09 15:26:52.861  14874-14874/com.rcd.simpleregister D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-09 15:26:52.865  14874-14874/com.rcd.simpleregister E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rcd.simpleregister, PID: 14874
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
            at com.rcd.simpleregister.DatabaseHelper.getSum(DatabaseHelper.java:90)
            at com.rcd.simpleregister.MyFragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java:31)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1137)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1326)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Anyone see why I might be getting this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Context` you passed to `SQLiteOpenHelper` super constructor was null.

The code you posted doesn't exactly show where the value for `mContext` comes from. In any case, in a fragment you should really have only a no-arg constructor, and you can use `getActivity()` for a `Context` when the fragment is attached to an activity.

Comment: You are right... not sure how that slipped past me.  I change the value i was throwing in the activity and its working fine now.  Thanks for that.. sometimes i need to be smacked around!  Will accept the answer once it lets me.